# How to get all inherited objects of a particular object of a model in django

Tags: django, django-models

I have these models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255)

class Manager(User):
    experience_in_field_in_years = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

class SalesPerson(User):
    current_hourly_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    work_timings = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Role(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class UserRole(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("User", related_name="user_roles", on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

Observer that `User` model is inherited by `Manager`, `SalesPerson`: there is a `parent_link` being generated as `user_ptr_id` to `User` table.

Now, whenever I create a manager/sales_person, a user is auto created.

A user can be both manager and sales_person. So, How to find/group a user with its child models? If I get a user from `User`, I need a way to know that he is a manager cum sales_person or only manager.

```
manager = Manager.objects.get(pk=2) #here 2 is actually the user id-> User model
manager.name #white
manager.experience_in_field_in_years #5
```

The above works. But,

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=2)
user.name #white
user.experience_in_field_in_years #error!! doesn't work. I want this to work.
```

**Another query** Should I use the `Role`, `UserRole` models? since I am already creating separate models for the respective roles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the `User` object has a `manager` or `salesperson` attribute:

```
if hasattr(user, 'manager'):
    # then object is a manager instance

if hasattr(user, 'salesperson'):
    # then object is a salesperson instance
```

Comment: Should I use the Role, UserRole models? since I am already creating separate models for the respective roles?

Comment: This was not part of the original question. You should however be able to use the `UserRole`. As long as you pass the user object to the `hasattr` method.

Comment: I do however not really see the need for the `UserRole/Role` models as it only has one field that links to `User`. This is open to interpretation though as I don't know what your end goal is. The above should work for the original question.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at the django extension polymorphic-models https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

```
from polymorphic.models import PolymorphicModel

class User(PolymorphicModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255)

class Manager(User):
    experience_in_field_in_years = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

class SalesPerson(User):
    current_hourly_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    work_timings = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Then user in the following code is a Manager instance

`Manager.objects.create(name='manager')
user = User.objects.get(name='manager')`